# How to obtain the object values from an array with one object and create a new array with just the object values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following array with just one object:

```
let myVar = [
  {
    "v1": "A",
    "v2": "B",
    "v3": "C",
    "v4": "D"
  }
]
```

How can I create a new array with just the object values alone from the above `myVar` array, i.e. the `newArray` should now be:

```
let newArray = [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ]
```

Just unsure how to solve this.

Comment: needs more conditions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that it will only have one object then all you need to do is:

```js
Object.values(myVar[0])
```

see docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Note: If you need to support older browsers like internet explorer you will have to use `Object.keys` paired with `map`

Answer (score 0):

Try This,
You get the result you want.

```
let newArr = [];
for (var key in myVar[0]) {
    if (myVar[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newArr.push(myVar[0][key]);
    }
}
console.log('New Array: ',newArr);
```

> Output: [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can think of:

Using for...in statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

```js
let newArray = [];
for (const property in myVar[0]) {
  newArray.push(object[property]);
}
```

Or using Object.entries() method combining with for...in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 0):

**Provided that** the array has just one object, you can simply assign `Object.values` of that particular object to a new variable.

`Array.prototype.values()` method returns a new Array Iterator object that contains the values for each index in the array. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)

```js
let myVar = [
  {
    "v1": "A",
    "v2": "B",
    "v3": "C",
    "v4": "D"
  }
]
const newArr = Object.values(myVar[0]);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: What is the use of `array#map`?

Comment: [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns an array so no need to use `map` here

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce method with spread syntax if your array has multiple Object.

```
const newArray = myVar.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return [...acc, ...Object.values(curr)];
}, [])

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to get all values of an object

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable property values

```js
let myVar = [{
  v1: "A",
  v2: "B",
  v3: "C",
  v4: "D",
}, ];

const newArray = Object.values(myVar[0]);
console.log(newArray);
```