# How do I create a new object with key as one object's value and the object as the value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My question is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008391/how-to-obtain-the-object-values-from-an-array-with-one-object-and-create-a-new-a)

I have a map with the key as objectType1 and value as objectType1 | null.

```
type ObjectType1 = { key:string , value:string }
const newMap = new Map<ObjectType1, Array<ObjectType1>|null>([
   [{key:'key1', value:'value1'},null],
]);
```

what I want to do here is that I want a new object which looks something like:

```
const newObject = {
   key1 : {key: 'key1', value:'value1'}
 }
```

So basically the new object should be able to reference to the object. If i do newObject.key1, i should be able to get the object {key: 'key1', value:'value1'}

How do I go about this?

Comment: Your example has several errors in it (at least one typo, and `null` is not of type `Array<objectType1> | null>`; please [edit] it so that it can be pasted into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue and only your issue.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N71Z4W) work for you?  Note that the type of `newObject` is going to be something like `{[k: string]: ObjectType1 | undefined}`.  The compiler has no idea that `key1` in particular is a key, since `newMap`'s type doesn't specify that.  If that works I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to iterate over the `Map`'s keys and collect them into an object.  Here's one:

```
const newObject =
  Array.from(newMap.keys()).
    reduce<Record<string, ObjectType1 | undefined>>(
      (acc, k) => ({ ...acc, [k.key]: k }), {}
    );
// const newObject: Record<string, ObjectType1 | undefined>
```

Here we are using [the `keys()` method of `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) to get an iterable iterator of all the key objects.  This is not an array, and since we're going to use [the `reduce()` method of `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to process it, we first need to convert it into an array via [the `Array.from()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

So `Array.from(newMap.keys())` is now an array of the keys, and we use `reduce()` to collate these into an object.  We do this by starting with the empty object `{}`, and, for each element `k` in the key array, we [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the previous object into a new object, and add a new property with key `k.key` and value `k`.

Note that the type of `newObject` is `Record<string, ObjectType1 | undefined>`, using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).  It has a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures); that means the TypeScript compiler has no idea what the keys of `newObject` will actually be.  Only that, for every key in `newObject`, the property *value* will be of type `ObjectType1 | undefined`.  (That `undefined` possibility is just there so that if you write `newObject.someKeyThatDoesNotActuallyExist` the compiler won't falsely claim that there's a property there of type `ObjectType1`.  You have to handle possible `undefined`/missing properties).

Okay, let's test it out:

```
console.log(newObject.key1)
// { "key": "key1", "value": "value1" }
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AFXBAjFAvFAbygGsIQAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMAaKANwEMAbAVwiUaDFlAC+AKGQB7RjSiMIAdwCyXMHgXKoasAB54SVBkhZ2AQVq0uIA4hTpMWAHxQAPgr48ezgBQBtCSgofyJSCigAcnCsSPZufkEohIFY8XZGLx4AXVYJbIBKAG4JKVl5RSVDBzwgqEtrEAA6ADNaaQBbX0rdJvCqXwKCprrg2ggAEz5kCD0AJRRpWgm9YSY2WHtjJ3coPkYJiBamSec-UeCoXy5kZHZiArxXXyImt5u7kOI+smzKYnEBXYBEklygxQkAHpIVAZHJgFoqltgJQFjJlqs6Ot2NVtqZdvtDsdFBNnKU4VRpDwIE0eNJmN1lLjgD8QFgClCYUQAEThbmUXlkLDc9jclIQflQMW8VLc8RQIA)